# VERY slow lateral join on relatively small database

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-12

My database consists of **apps** and their **reviews** (schema below). I'm trying to answer the following question:

*Given a series of dates from the earliest `reviews.review_date` to the latest `reviews.review_date` (incrementing by a day), for each date, D, which apps had the most reviews if the app's earliest review was on or later than D?*

This is the query that I've come up with to try and answer that question:

```sql
select
  review_windows.review_window_start,
  id,
  slug,
  review_total,
  earliest_review
from
  (
    select
      date_trunc('day', review_windows.review_windows) :: date as review_window_start
    from
      generate_series(
        (
          SELECT
            min(reviews.review_date)
          FROM
            reviews
        ),
        (
          SELECT
            max(reviews.review_date)
          FROM
            reviews
        ),
        '1 day'
      ) review_windows
    order by
      1 desc
  ) review_windows
  left join lateral (
    SELECT
      apps.id,
      apps.slug,
      count(reviews.*) as review_total,
      min(reviews.review_date) as earliest_review
    FROM
      reviews
      INNER JOIN apps ON apps.id = reviews.app_id
    where
      reviews.review_date >= review_windows.review_window_start
    group by
      1,
      2
    having
      min(reviews.review_date) >= review_windows.review_window_start
    order by
      3 desc,
      4 desc
    limit
      2
  ) apps_most_reviews on true;
```

It is **extremely** slow and I'm not sure why. If I want any kinds of results I use `week` instead of `day` in the `generate_series` call and even then that might take a minute or even longer.

Where should I start when debugging a performance issue like this?

Visualized query plan [here](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/xLO)

There are ~5K rows in `apps` and ~400K rows in `reviews` so it's a mystery to me why this is taking so long.

Running the individual subquery that is run for each entry in the lateral join given a single date only takes `161 ms` (below) and the subquery for `generate_series` only takes `4 ms`. I'm clearly doing something very wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Individual subquery with an explicit date

```sql
SELECT
  apps.id,
  apps.slug,
  count(reviews.*) as review_total,
  min(reviews.review_date) as earliest_review
FROM
  reviews
  INNER JOIN apps ON apps.id = reviews.app_id
where
  reviews.review_date >= '2018-04-17'::date
group by
  1,
  2
having
  min(reviews.review_date) >= '2018-04-17'::date
order by
  3 desc,
  4 desc
limit
  2
```

## Tables

### `apps`

**Schema**

```
|   | column_name | data_type    | is_nullable | foreign_key |
|---|-------------|--------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1 | id          | int4         | NO          |             |
| 2 | name        | varchar(255) | NO          |             |
| 3 | slug        | varchar(255) | NO          |             |
```

**Indexes**

```
| index_name      | index_algorithm | is_unique | column_name |
|-----------------|-----------------|-----------|-------------|
| apps_slug_index | BTREE           | t         | slug        |
| apps_pkey       | BTREE           | t         | id          |
```

### `reviews`

**Schema**

```
|   | column_name   | data_type    | is_nullable | foreign_key     |
|---|---------------|--------------|-------------|-----------------|
| 1 | id            | int4         | NO          |                 |
| 2 | rating        | int4         | NO          |                 |
| 3 | review_date   | date         | NO          |                 |
| 4 | reviewer_name | varchar(255) | NO          |                 |
| 5 | review_body   | text         | NO          |                 |
| 6 | app_id        | int4         | NO          | public.apps(id) |
```

**Indexes**

```
| index_name                  | index_algorithm | is_unique | column_name   |
|-----------------------------|-----------------|-----------|---------------|
| reviews_reviewer_name_index | BTREE           | f         | reviewer_name |
| reviews_review_date_index   | BTREE           | f         | review_date   |
| reviews_pkey                | BTREE           | t         | id            |
| reviews_app_id_index        | BTREE           | f         | app_id        |
```

Comment: What is the plan for the single-day query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for the slowness is that you aggregate over the big table from scratch for every iteration of the lateral sibquery. Compute earliest review & current total count per app in a CTE *once* and base the lateral subquery on it. I discussed that and some other optizations under your predating related question on SO:

- [Get apps with the highest review count since a dynamic series of days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63320975/939860)

One difference: In this question you also return an additional attribute of the app (`slug`), so we need to join to table `apps` after all. Literally: join to `apps` *after* aggregating `reviews`. That's cheaper.

Another difference: `earliest_review` as additioal tiebreaker. That's just a gradual improvement, though, as there can stiill be 0-n winners per `review_window_start`. Instead of picking the (arbitrary) top two ( `limit 2`), select the *first one, with ties*. (Wording already hints at the new technique in Postgres 13; see below.)

```sql
WITH cte AS MATERIALIZED (
   SELECT a.id, a.slug, r.earliest_review, r.review_total
   FROM   apps a
   JOIN    (
      SELECT app_id, min(review_date) AS earliest_review, count(*)::int AS review_total
      FROM   reviews
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) r ON r.app_id = a.id
   )
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT generate_series(min(review_date)
                        , max(review_date)
                        , '1 day')::date
   FROM   reviews
   ) d(review_window_start)
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT app_id, slug, review_total, earliest_review
   FROM  (
      SELECT app_id, slug, review_total, earliest_review
            ,  rank() OVER (ORDER BY review_total DESC, earliest_review DESC) AS rnk
      FROM   cte c
      WHERE  c.earliest_review >= d.review_window_start
      ) sub
   WHERE  rnk = 1
   ) a ON true;
```

Like in the related answer on SO, it will be cheaper yet in **Postgres 13** using **`WITH TIES`**. See:

- [Greater than or equal to ALL() and equal to MAX() speed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63184287/939860)

```sql
...
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT app_id, slug, review_total, earliest_review
   FROM   cte c
   WHERE  earliest_review >= d.review_window_start
   ORDER  BY review_total DESC, earliest_review DESC
   FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES  -- new!
   ) a ON true;
```

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed explanation and solution. I really, really appreciate it.